# why can't i get distance matrix api to work between 2 countries

Tags: api, matrix, distance

OK I have the Distance Matrix API working just fine for cities in the same country.  It can be US or France.  But when I put Paris,France and Austin,TX USA I get zero results. I have tried austin,tx only and with the USA - nothing.  If I stay in the same country no problem.  Any ideas?

{ destination_addresses: [ 'Austin, TX, USA' ],

origin_addresses: [ 'Paris, France' ],

rows: [ { elements: [Array] } ],

status: 'OK' }

[ { elements: [ [Object] ] } ]

[ { status: 'ZERO_RESULTS' } ]

Comment: Have you considered that maybe it is impossible to travel from Austin to Paris by car because there is some ocean between them?

Comment: Benjamin Barrois - well yes there is water but tell me then why doesn't Ontario Canada to Austin TX USA work either.  There is no water between them?!?

Comment: This time the problem is that Ontario is a state, not a locality. You have to give more information. Try a canadian city where there is a road and you'll see.